am getting 'System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure- multiple times on postgreSQLDB
I am using postgresql server 13 on on premises server machine (Windows 12 VM). I am getting below error sometimes and it works sometime.
What is the cause for this error?

It works fine when I restart the application or the server but it is not good practice.
